# C# Webform Accessing Master Page's Public Property

Tags: c#, asp.net

So this is my public property master page:

```
public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
{
    public string _AllowedRoles = "";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

How can I access `_AllowedRoles` from the master page itself (Site.Master)?

```
<script>
    var allowedRole = <% _AllowedRoles %> //Does not exist
</script>
```

---

Note

---

Tried with `var allowedRole = <%= this._AllowedRoles%>` still does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP when using server tags in HTML, if you create a string, with a value of let's say `bar` and a property name of `prop`. You need to wrap them in quotes or it will be seen as a variable name.

So this: `var foo = <%=prop%>` will result in `var foo = bar`. Where `bar` does not exist in the context and will be null or throw an error depending on weather you are `using strict` or not.

```
var allowedRole = "<%=_AllowedRoles %>"
```

Comment: the problem is the `_AllowedRoles` does not exist on the Site.Master. How can I access it?